# How to reach a dynamic UIView from another function that called by a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got this code, what I want it to do, is to create a few UIViews on the screen, with a button on them, and when you click on the button that is located on-top of the UIView, the UIView it self will perform animation and will flip to the other side, when you click on the button that is on the UIView's other side, again, it will flip back.

So i've created my UIView's dynamically, but I have a problem, the button is performing the action, but the view wont performing the animation because I dont know how to reach out to the specific UIView.

How can I do it?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    arrImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image001.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image002.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image003.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image004.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image005.JPG"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image006.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image007.jpeg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image008.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image009.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image010.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image001.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image002.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image003.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image004.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image005.JPG"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image006.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image007.jpeg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image008.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image009.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image010.png"], nil];

    x = 0;
    btnFrameX = 18;
    btnFrameY = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrImages count]; i++)
    {
        if (btnFrameX <= 237)
        {
            //  Create views of cards

            UIView * first = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btnFrameX, btnFrameY, 65, 65)];
            UIView * secod = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65)];
            UIView * third = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65)];

            first.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1%i",i]intValue];
            secod.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2%i",i]intValue];
            third.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3%i",i]intValue];

            NSLog(@"1%i",i);
            NSLog(@"2%i",i);
            NSLog(@"3%i",i);

            UILabel * cardLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65)];
            cardLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i+1];

            UIButton * cardBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [cardBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65)];
            [cardBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cardBtn setImage:[arrImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [cardBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [secod addSubview:cardLabel];
            [third addSubview:cardBtn];
            [first addSubview:secod];
            [first addSubview:third];
            [self.view addSubview:first];

            btnFrameX = btnFrameX + 73;
        }
        if (btnFrameX > 237)
        {
            btnFrameX = 18;
            btnFrameY = btnFrameY + 73;
        }
    }


-(IBAction) flipView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    // Should hide the one that you clicked on and show the other one.
    [self showOtherView];
    // flipping the mainview (first), he's the one that the other 2 UIViews (second and third) attached on.
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:first cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) showOtherView
{    
    if (x == 0)
    {
        x = 1;
        second.hidden = NO;
        third.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
        second.hidden = YES;
        third.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

I hope I explained myself well, If not, please ask me and I will answer.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is subview of the UIView you want to reach, isn't it ?

If so, it s very simple : set a selector and target to your button,

```
[cardBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Declare your function,

```
-(void)flipView:(UIButton*)sender;
```

The clicked button will be in the sender parameter. So :

```
-(void)flipView:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIView * reachedView = [sender superview];
    /* make what you want with the reached view ! */
}
```

EDIT :

In your description, you want two buttons: one on each side. 1st side is viewA and 2nd side is viewB. viewA & viewB belong to mainView.

```
UIButton btA = ...
UIButton btB = ...
[btA addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btB addTarget:self action:@selector(flipView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[viewA addSubview:btA];
[viewB addSubview:btB];
[mainView addSubview:viewA];
[mainView addSubview:viewB];
```

now in flip view :

```
-(void)flipView:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIView * mainView = [[sender superview] superview]; // the first for viewA or B, the second for mainView...
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:mainView cache:YES];
    [mainView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Does it correspond to your problem ?

Comment: Thanks man, the animation is working and the view is flipping, but I have another problem, how can I set the specific 'second' & 'third' view to be hidden or showen, because I can only reach the sender, which is the 'first' view.

Comment: It seems that you are using tags. If so, you can use - (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag, in the first view, to retreive the good one.

Comment: How can I use it? how can I reach to the 'second' & 'third' UIView's. because the first is flipping, but I only use in the 'second' & 'third' in the "-(void) showOtherView", so how can I reach to those 2 UIView's in there?

Comment: Cool man, that works perfectly! thank you very much for your big big help! :)

Comment: I want to create a Memory Card game, so, how can I do that when you click on an image, it flips of course, I want to check the image on the button, and if it equals to the image that on the second button that i clicked on, they will fade out and disappear. how can I compare them? because each time its just one button... its kinda complicated for me, i'm new to obj-c :( what should I do?

Comment: I think you should... no, you must create a class "MemoryCard" that inherits from UIView. This class should subview the two faces of the card, and have a property that identifies the card (like "spade king", or "heart queen"). You even can create a typedef enum which lists each value of your game cards. But that's not objC, it is oriented object programming...

Comment: ok, thanks allot man. you helped me more than I wish for. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

declare a property UIView.

```
UIView *flippedVew;
//set property.
```

When a button is clicked on a view, **set the property** and your button action(where you perform the animation) do the animation on that view. similarly, when button on another view is clicked , set the property to that view.